# Running multiple commands through exec()

Tags: php, python, exec, blender, var

I need to pass a variable from php to a python script in blender.

Essentially this should work:

```
exec("start cmd /k cd C:\Blender & set arg1='file' & blender -P [path to python file]");
```

Instead it just changes the directory to C:\Blender and stops. It seems as though php's exec() doesn't like using "&" to run multiple commands after one another.

I'm assuming this because when I open cmd my self and type:

```
cd C:\Blender & set arg1='file' & blender -P [path to python file]
```

It opens blender and runs the python script which prints the arg1, (file).

Does anyone have any ideas as supposed to how one can run multiple commands with the exec() in php. Or maybe I should try a different method to pass the php variable to the blender python script.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you run a gui app from php? Try shell_exec(), chdir() before exec(). Are you running safe mode? then only cmd's in safe_mode_exec_dir can be run. Also you probably want to add `-b` so blender runs without gui. Search for windexec on [php manual for exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) where an example creates a COM object to run a cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg).
when this is used, it treats your entire argument as single safe argument.

So you can use,

```
$variableToPass = "start cmd /k cd C:\Blender & set arg1='file' & blender -P [path to python file]";
exec(escapeshellarg($variableToPass));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work, (cmd isn't opened at all).